# Capybara open window does not work when link is a modal with href javascript=void(0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I am using capybara window_opened_by with success but in one specific test, the window thta opens is a Facebook dialog (it opens as a modal "above" the other window) and in that case the test fails.

to be precise, when the user click on a link, it does not open a new tab but opens up a "popup". It's exactly the same type of popup as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/

**view.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-xs-4 action-facebook" id="js-fbShareBtn">       
        <a  
            href="javascript:void(0)"
            title="Share on Facebook"
            target="_blank"            
            rel="noreferrer">          
Share on facebook
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

**Rspec test.rb**

```
it "on deal page button SHARE works effectively", js: true do
  visit deal_page_path(deal_path) 
  facebook_window = window_opened_by do
    click_link 'Share on Facebook'
  end
  within_window facebook_window do
    expect(page).to have_css("html#facebook")
  end       
end
```

The facebook modal is activated by juavascript:

```
function activateFbShareBtn() {
    $fbShareBtn.on('click', function(e) {
          FB.ui({
            method:         'share',
            mobile_iframe:  true,
            display:        'popup',
            href:           gon.deal_actual_url,
          }, function(response){});
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I get this error message:

```
Capybara::WindowError:
       block passed to #window_opened_by opened 0 windows instead of 1
```

I checked and if I change href in the view from   href="javascript:void(0)" to a standard link such as   href="https://www.example.com"  then the test fails (that's normal as the expected content is not on www.example.com) but at least I don't get this  Capybara::WindowError error. So I am pretty sure this is the reason.

How can I make this work? How to test a modal that opens not a standard href link but on a href="javascript:void(0)"

EDIT: After suggestions that the issue was likely more related to some javascript error, I tracked it down and found out the bug was due to the fact the call to facebook sdk library had not been whitelisted in rspec:

```
config.allow_url("https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js")
```

Comment: Is it actually opening a new window/tab ?? Or is it just creating a JS driven HTML modal structure in the same window/tab?

Comment: it's opening a modal. The right word to describe it is "popup" (note sure it's the best word as the line between modal, popup...are often blurry to me) I'll try to find an example to show.

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Edited my question to be more precise about the type of "entity" opened by the click on the link

Comment: https://gist.github.com/twalpole/b3b4d786a2ffac068cfe049b5baaf3b8 works fine with the example jsfiddle you posted -  Are you sure the window is actually opening and that you don't have an error (JS possibly) occuring before that? Another possibility is to try increasing `Capybara.default_max_wait_time`.  What JS driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I use WebKit. I thought too I might have js error but I placed a very visual change $logo.css('color', ´red') as close as possible (before and after) the block "FB.ui" and then when i redo the test using save_and_open_page , I can see the logo has changed color to red so I think the js works fine. But I could dig deeper in this direction...

Comment: I'll check default max time too later at home

Comment: found out why i had an issue. Damn me:) Forgotten to whitelist the call to fb sdk.js config.allow_url("https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"). that's why it was "failing silently"...

Comment: Also, interesting: the test still give me from time to time (same test/just different runs) the same error but less frequently: adding sleep 5 just before the "facebook_window = window_opened_by do" allows me to pass it 100% of the time. It must have sth to do with allowing the fb sdk call executed by the javascript to have time to download it and go all the way...

Comment: Rather than sleeping, you should make it so the link is disabled until `sdk.js` has completed loading, which would then allow the test to sync up (since click_link will wait for the link to be enabled)

Comment: You're right, I know that sleep is quite tricky and should be avoided when necessary. Actually I kind of do what you suggest: before the fb sdk is "active", I needed to users to ALREADY be able to click (so it goes beyond removing the links they must be able immediately to click), so I have a fallback which is also a href empty and activated by javascript which does not need fb sdk (an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/ but mine is 100% injected by javascript)

Comment: So to test this, I would in the end like to test 1.  using puffing billy to stub a long time for sdk download, assert that before sdk is active when user clicks on the link, a popup opens with current_url  = fallback strategy (no need fb sdk) = starts with http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php... , and  2. using puffing billy, when fb sdk is finally active, when he clicks on the link, a popup opens with current_url (url when the fb sdk is used= sth starting with https://www.facebook.com/v2.11/dialog/share)

Comment: ...the problem today is to do this I need puffing billy and I am facing this bug: https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy/issues/215 so waiting to solve this bug before implementing my test 1. and 2 :-)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thanks for helping me see this through.greatly appreciated

Comment: You're welcome - added details as an answer so you can accept and mark this question as answered/closed -- I also commented on your puffing-billy bug.

Comment: double thanks for the answer on the github!

Comment: solved the puffing billy mystery, see https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy/issues/215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the comments on the main question, this was more likely to be a JS error (and turned out to be a JS file not being loaded due to the `capybara-webkit` whitelist) than anything to do with the actual link. Since `capybara-webkit` is being used this error could have been caught sooner if you enable `raise_javascript_errors` in your `capybara-webkit` configuration - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#configuration

Comment: wow that's a configuration super useful i did not know about. thanks.